# Manipulate module variables from another module

Tags: python, variables, module

Recently I have been attempting to make somewhat of a home assistant. Inside the home assistant, there are modules that run in a handler script. I have imported a module that I created to play youtube videos through my raspberry pi. What I want to do is update a variable in my youtube module inside of my handler script. Here is what I have so far:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import subprocess
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import time
import urllib, json, sys
from six import string_types
from signal import pause
from omxplayer.player import OMXPlayer
from gpiozero import Button
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process
from keys import key

button_pause = Button(17)
button_quit = Button(2)
button_skip = Button(3)
var_pause = False
var_skip = False
var_quit = False

DEVELOPER_KEY = key.api_keys['YOUTUBE_API']
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = 'v3'

'''

OMXPLAYER

'''

class Player:

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.player = None
        self.state = True
        self.playlist = False
        self._play = True

    def start(self):
        if isinstance(self.url, string_types):
            cmd = 'youtube-dl -g -f best {0}'.format(self.url)
            yt_dl = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
            (url, err) = yt_dl.communicate()
            if yt_dl.returncode != 0:
                sys.stderr.write(err)
                print('error')
            yurl = url.decode('UTF-8').strip()
            self.player = OMXPlayer(yurl, args=['-o','hdmi'])
            return self.player.duration()

    def stop(self):
        self.player.stop()
        self._play = False
        self.player = None
        return False

    def skip(self):
        if self.playlist == True:
            self.player.stop()
            return True
        else:
            self.player.stop()
            return False

    def toggle(self):
        #false = not playing // true = playing
        if self.state == True:
            self.state = False
            self.player.pause()
        elif self.state == False:
            self.state = True
            self.player.play()
        else:
            return False

    def is_play(self):
        return self.player.can_control()






class Handlers:

    def __init__(self):
        self.url = None
        self.typeof = None
        self.proc = None
        self._play = True
        self.player = None
        self.players = None

    def input_handler(self):
        if self.typeof == 'video':
            #print(url)
            self.players = [Player(self.url)]
            self.player = self.players[0]
            print('url for video:: {0}'.format(self.player.url))
            self.player.start()
            #self.proc = Process(target = self.output_handler)
            #self.proc.start
            self.output_handler()
        elif self.typeof == 'playlist':
            for video in self.url:
                if self._play == True:
                    print(self._play)
                    #print(video)
                    self.players = [Player(video)]
                    self.player = self.players[0]
                    print('url for playlist video:: {0}'.format(self.player.url))
                    self.player.playlist = True
                    self.player.start()
                    #self.proc = Process(target = self.output_handler)
                    #self.proc.start()
                    self.output_handler()
                else:
                    return False

    def output_handler(self):
        global button_quit
        global button_pause
        global button_skip
        global var_quit
        global var_pause
        global var_skip
        if self._play == True:
            #player.start()
            time.sleep(2.5)
            p = self.player
            p.playlist = True
            if p is not None:
                try:
                    while p.is_play():
                        if self._play == True:
                            if button_quit.is_pressed:
                                p.stop()
                                self._play = False
                                return False
                            elif button_pause.is_pressed:
                                p.toggle()
                                time.sleep(1)
                            elif button_skip.is_pressed:
                                if p.playlist == True:
                                    p.skip()
                                    return True
                                else:
                                    p.stop()
                                    return False
                                time.sleep(1)

                            elif var_skip == True:
                                var_skip = False
                                if p.playlist == True:
                                    p.skip()
                                    return True
                                else:
                                    p.stop()
                                    return False
                                time.sleep(1)
                            elif var_quit == True:
                                p.stop()
                                self._play = False
                                var_quit = False
                                return False
                            elif var_pause == True:
                                print('pausing')
                                p.toggle()
                                time.sleep(1)
                                var_pause = False

                            else:
                                time.sleep(0.1)
                                print(var_pause, var_quit, var_skip)
                                global var_quit
                                global var_pause
                                global var_skip
                                p.is_play()
                        else:
                            print('not playable')
                            return False
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Something went wrong. Here it is: {0}".format(e))
```

NOTE: SOME OF THE CODE HAS BEEN CUT OUT FOR READABILITY PURPOSES

You can make note of that Output handler inside the handler class. What I want to do is manipulate the var_skip, var_pause and var_quit from another module in order to be able to stop/play my video.

Inside of my handler script, I pop open a separate process to run the youtube so it runs in the background. My buttons seem to update proficiently when pressed. But when I try and access my variables from my handler script nothing happens. Here is my handler script

```
from modules import news
from modules import weather
from modules import sms
from modules import timers
from modules import define
from modules import youtube
from keys import key
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import requests
import json
import datetime
import os


############################################

mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
HOST = key.mqtt_keys[0]
PORT = int(key.mqtt_keys[1])
TOPICS = key.mqtt_topics
timer = None
youtube_process
#API KEYS
YOUTUBE_API = key.api_keys['YOUTUBE_API']
WEATHER_API = key.api_keys['WEATHER_API']
YANDEX_API = key.api_keys['YANDEX_API']


def playVideo(query):
    global youtube_process
    youtube_process = Process(target = youtube.Youtube, args = [query,])
    youtube_process.start()






#############################################


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global timer
    if msg.topic not in TOPICS:
        return False
    os.system('aplay /home/pi/snips-custom-hotword/resources/dong.wav')
    slots = parse_slots(msg)
    #print(str(slots))

    if msg.topic == 'hermes/intent/searchWeatherForecast':
        weather = getWeather()
        time = slots.get("forecast_start_datetime", None)
        location = slots.get("forecast_locality", None)
        set = handleWeather(weather, time, location)
        response = set

    elif msg.topic == 'hermes/intent/nickdeb:speakerInterrupt':
        global youtube_process
        keyword = slots.get("keyword", None)
        if keyword:
            if keyword == 'pause' or keyword == 'Pause' or keyword == 'paused':
                response = 'Pausing your music!'
                youtube_process.var_pause = True
            else:
                response = 'Stopping your music'
                youtube_process.var_quit = True
        else:
            response = 'Stopping your music!'
            youtube.var_quit = True
    elif msg.topic == 'hermes/intent/nextSong':
        youtube.var_skip = True
        response = 'Skipping your song'

    elif msg.topic == 'hermes/intent/resumeMusic':
        youtube.var_pause = True
        response = 'Resuming your music!'

    elif msg.topic == 'hermes/intent/playArtist':
        query = slots.get("artist_name", None) + ' top tracks'
        youtubes = playVideo(query)
        response = 'Playing top tracks by {1}'.format(msg.topic, slots.get("artist_name", None))
    elif msg.topic == 'hermes/intent/nickdeb:playSong':
        youtubes = playVideo(slots.get("song_name", None))
        response = 'Playing {0} for you'.format(slots.get("song_name", None))
```

I have tried both editing the process's module variables and just the regular module variable and nothing has worked. Please help! Thank you!

TLDR; Change a modules variable from a handler script and update it realtime. The module is inside a process and the variable is a global variable that I want to access. The variable is used inside of a class

Comment: Can you use setter functions? So that you call `module.stop()`, `module.skip()` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a separate process, the *current* global state is copied to the new process.  Any changes you make afterward (like changing global variables) aren't going to be shared with the other process.

The `multiprocessing` package has tools to help [share state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

In this case, you probably want to use a `Manager` to share these settings between the processes, rather than global variables.

```
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process

manager = Manager()
state = manager.dict()
state['pause'] = False
state['skip'] = False
state['quit'] = False

youtube_process = Process(target = youtube.Youtube, args=(query, state))

# Process will get this change.
state['quit'] = True
```